# Exporting data from php to excel document

Tags: php, sql, excel, export-to-excel

I have numerous variables calculated from SQL db and I would like to generate a excel document from the results. I was wondering what is the best way to specify the cells you want to insert these variable into? For example $consumable_sum => A2, so when I generate the excel sheet cell A2 should have what contains $consumable_sum. In addition what is the best way to generate a excel document. I have searched through the internet and there are many ways. Many thanks!

Comment: use any php excel library and follow the documentation part..my personal preference http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Make sure you understand whether these libraries create a real Excel file (BIFF or OfficeOpenXML formats), or simply a CSV file or HTML markup masquerading as an Excel file.... don't rely on a file being generated with an xls extension as being a real Excel file